# If the plural of ‘man’ is ‘men,’ shouldn’t the plural of ‘German’ be ‘Germen’?

Tags: etymology, nouns, grammatical-number, demonyms

What makes these two words so different that 'man' is changed to 'men', but 'German' is changed to 'Germans'?

Comment: We humen like to bend rules and be creative.

Comment: The answer to "should English be consistent in spelling?" is quite different to the answer to "**is** English consistent in spelling?"...

Comment: Yeah, and since the plural of _tooth_ is _teeth_, I suppose the plural of _booth_ should have been _beeth_. And since we say that the teacher _taught_, we must also say that the preacher _praught_. That was a light-hearted way of saying the same thing as @progo's comment : We sure like to bend rules and be creative. Words have all sorts of reasons to be in their present form. Nowadays, I hear that people are facebook-ing (keeping in contact through facebook), kik-ing (messaging on kik) and SMS-ing (sending a text message in your mobile phone) each other :-)

Comment: Why won't we have equality and change history to theirtory?

Comment: The British invasion by the Romen was followed up by waves of alien hordes, culminating in the conquest of the Normen.

Comment: afikoman, Bildungsroman, ceriman, caiman, daman, desman, dhaman, dolman, firman,
Haman, hetman, human, Künstlerroman, leman, liman, Mussulman, Naman,
Norman, Oklahoman, ottoman, Ottoman, Panaman, Pullman, pygman,
Quartodeciman, Roman, saman, shaman, talisman, Tallman, terjiman, Tolman,
truchman, Turcoman, Turkman.

Comment: If people from Poland are called Poles, why aren't people from Holland called Holes? :)

Comment: Check out the [Chaos poem](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~jnb/charivarius.html); English is more frelled than that!  (Granted, it's more about pronunciation than pluralization; I think it still makes my point ^_^)

Comment: @grep: That only works with a single "l", not with a double "ll".

Comment: Three remarks **germānus** in Latin, means originally: _close, coming from the same stem, having the same father_, then _true, proved, genuine, of good quality, on which you can rely_ (as should be the trust you have in your brother). It is a very common adjective in the classical language. One interpretation is that by transfer, it became the name of those tribes east of the Rhine that looked alike for those who lived west of the Rhine. **Germen** exists in Latin as a noun it means _a sprout, a bud, an offshoot._ **Hermano** meaning brother in Spanish comes from the Latin germanus.

Comment: gerMENSCH, maybe. You're approximating a foreign word, there.

Comment: Bradd Szonye's answer proves this is an unfounded question. Why is this 'protected' -- I see no justification other than preventing a comment like this.

Comment: Voting to close as NARQ. When the tag is etymology, why was the etymology of 'German(y)' not researched and cited in the question?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_Germany#Etymology http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_Germany http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country-name_etymologies#G

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are plurals ‘\*humen’ and ‘\*Germen’ not conventional?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280510/why-are-plurals-humen-and-germen-not-conventional)

Comment: @tchrist, the putative duplicate was asked 2 days ago; this was asked in 2013. "This question has been asked *before*..." does not apply.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

[*German*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/German) is from the Latin word *germani*; unlike the similar-looking demonyms *Englishman* and *Frenchman,* it is etymologically unrelated to the word *man* and does not form a plural the same way.

Comment: This is correct. It is nothing more than a coincidence that these two words happen to use the same set of three letters. (I would merely mention that the Latin name of Germany was Germania, not germani).

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg That's correct: _Germania_ is the land, _germani_ is the people.

Comment: Remarkable. Out of all the words ending in –man at http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/ends_with.php it seems that only German and I suggest, caiman, shaman, and talisman don’t form a plural –men.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: [See](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111772/if-the-plural-of-man-is-men-shouldnt-the-plural-of-german-be-germen#comment227026_111772) [also](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111772/if-the-plural-of-man-is-men-shouldnt-the-plural-of-german-be-germen#comment227007_111772)  :)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok *afikoman, Bildungsroman, ceriman, daman, desman, dhaman, dolman, firman, Haman, hetman, human, Künstlerroman, leman, liman, Mussulman, Naman, Norman, Oklahoman, ottoman, Ottoman, Panaman, Pullman, pygman, Quartodeciman, Roman, saman, talisman, Tallman, terjiman, Tolman, truchman, Turcoman, Turkman.*

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: Even from the rather limited litscape.com list, you missed "human" and its derivatives (the list has "inhuman", "nonhuman", "subhuman" and "superhuman").

Comment: I'd upvote, but I don't want to destroy the perfect 100.

Comment: @Luke Fixed that for ya.

Comment: Might as well upvote now... Or should I downvote? *evil grin*

Comment: @Luke Ha! Thanks for the upvote _and_ the evil grin.

Comment: Evil grin retracted

Answer (score 26):

Words like *human* and *German* are not from *man* and do not contain the (Germanic) morpheme *man*, as you say. Only the morpheme *man* is properly pluralised as *men*. See the list of words in Tchrist's answer for an overview of which words are from *man* and which aren't. In *human* and *German*, we're dealing with the Latin suffix *-anus*, which means something vague like "having to do with x", shortened to *-an* in English.

Cf. *Republican* (same Latin suffix), *Qur'an* (an Arabic morpheme): we don't say *two Republicen were reading their Qur'en*.

The true etymology is very important, because folk etymology is not very common in general and hardly ever accepted by the "writing classes". So it does not often become popular enough to displace the original.

Further, there would be little difference in pronunciation between *human* and *humen*, because the last syllable is unstressed; folk etymology normally originates in speech, not writing, which means that this plural would be much less useful to speakers. (In *women*, a trick was performed by having a differently pronounced first syllable to distinguish between *woman* (/wʊ-/) and *women* (/wɪ-/), which words would otherwise be pronounced (almost) the same.)

Answer (score 18):

It’s because they are not, or are not thought of as being, composed of a base noun which the word *man* has been pasted on to the end of.  Without the word *man* to start with, you won’t get *men* out of the plural.

Here’s a longer list of such things:

- *ataman*
- *caiman*
- *cayman*
- *ceriman*
- *desman*
- *dolman*
- *farman*
- *harman*
- *hetman*
- *human*
- *leman*
- *ottoman*
- *shaman*
- *talisman*
- *Alabaman*
- *Bahaman*
- *Burman*
- *German*
- *Hiroshiman*
- *Liman*
- *Nakayaman*
- *Norman*
- *Oklahoman*
- *Panaman*
- *Roman*
- *Selman*
- *Sonaman*
- *Tacoman*
- *Yakiman*
- *Yokohaman*
- *Yuman*

In other words, there is no *man* morpheme present to  undergo that word’s (now irregular) i-mutation the way there is in these:

- ***air***man
- ***bails***man
- ***bar***man
- ***church***man
- ***draft***man
- ***frontier***man
- ***games***man
- ***handi***man
- ***highway***man
- ***Irish***man
- ***jury***man
- ***kins***man
- ***law***man
- ***mad***man
- ***noble***man
- ***Orkney***man
- ***pike***man
- ***quarry***man
- ***rag***man
- ***rifle***man
- ***Scots***man
- ***sea***man
- ***trades***man
- ***underclass***man
- ***vestry***man
- ***watch***man
- ***work***man
- ***yachts***man

See the difference?

Be aware that one on rare occasion still sees this pattern:

- *foramen > foramina*
- *gravamen > gravamina*
- *legumen > legumina*
- *molimen > molimina*
- *nomen > nomina*
- *stamen > stamina*
- *specimen > specimina*
- *tegmen > tegmina*
- *tentamen > tentamina*
- *velamen > velamina*

Most of those Latin inflections have now been assimilated into regular English plurals, except sometimes in scientific literature.

Comment: Of course the irony is that while this answer correctly identifies an etymological fallacy, it, in turn, is an etymological fallacy in its own right. The only *real* answer to the question "why is *humen* not acceptable" is "because nobody ever uses it, at all". If everyone did use it, it would be perfectly acceptable, or even the norm. The real answer to *any* why question about language is "because". There is no other answer. There is no reason. There can't be. It's all just chance. It just so happens.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Then answer me this question. Is it never useful to explain what factors caused a certain form to become used or not used, if such factors can be identified?

Comment: @RegDwigнt - I partly agree but Cerberus' answer gives an actual reason. It relates to the position of the stress. In modern English, 'human' and 'humen' would tend to be indistinguishable because the stress is on 'hu' and the final vowel would therefore be a schwa.  [Cross-posted with Cerberus' comment]

Comment: @Cerberus: oh if you *know* the factors, knock yourself out. But you seem to miss my point that more often than not *we just do not know* them. It's all idle speculation in hindsight. It's justification after the fact. As are, indeed, most grammar "rules", which are really but mere observations.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK oh yes, totally. So just to make sure I understand: are you saying that the stress in "firemen" and "policemen" falls on the *men*, or are you saying that the correct plural is "firemans" and "policemans"?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Sure, I agree that it is useless to talk about something that really isn't known at all. But how is the asker to know that in advance? Besides, in reality, we often do have an idea of some factors, and we put them in our answers. They are rarely 100% proven, but a substantiated argument can be quite useful, if we're not entirely sure.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: As to your comment on Chasly, read my answer, which answers your question (whether you agree with it ot not).

Answer (score 6):

As tchrist pointed out in his answer, it hinges on whether the word is considered to be *base descriptive word* + *man*. Some of your examples, like *German*, were never formed that way. However, the OED gives an example of *Normen* as a plural in Old English:

> OE   Anglo-Saxon Chron. (Tiber. B.i) anno 1066   Þær wæs Harold cyning of Norwegan & Tostig eorl ofslagen, & gerim folces mid heom, ægðer ge Normana ge Englisca, & þa Normen [flugon þa Englis[c]a].
>
> OE   Anglo-Saxon Chron. (Tiber. B.iv) anno 1049   Harold for to Norwegum, Magnus fædera, syððan Magnus dead wæs, & Normen hine underfengon.

Compare to *Englisman*, *Englishmen*, which are still both acceptable. I'd guess that as *Norman* became seen more as the name of the people, its plural became more regular. It stopped being a compound word and became a simple word.

Comment: The reason is probably that it came to English through French. The Germanic suffix -man is not known in French and less easily recognised by the French, so they probably said and wrote *Normans*. So there already was a plural on -s when the Normans invaded England. P.S. It's also interesting how they write *Normand* and *Normandie*. Cf. Dutch *niemand* for "noöne, no-man", which is also from *man* and also has the -d, which is odd in Dutch. I believe German also has inflected forms like *niemandem*?

Comment: Consider also the obsolete word _Mussulman_, which was a borrowing from Arabic _musulman_, meaning a Muslim. This does not contain the morpheme "man", but plural _Mussulmen_ was certainly found as well as _Mussulmans_. (The Arabic plural is _maslamin_ IIRC).

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, _niemand_ ‘noone, nobody’ and _jemand_ ‘someone, somebody’ are usually inflected in contemporary German: _+en_ Acc, _+em_ Dat, _+es_ Gen. They are of course related to the neutral 3rd person singular pronoun _man_ ‘one’ (or ‘you’) and the noun _Mann_ ‘man, male’.

Comment: My Anglo-Saxon isn't good enough to be sure who the "Normen" were: were they *Normans*, - i.e. French, or *Northmen* - i.e. the "Northumbrians" or "Norsemen" [actually Danes] of Tostig's army?

Comment: @alephzero the OED suggests that they are *North* men. But etymologically that's the same as the Normans.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying it- a man from France is called a Frenchman, and many of them are referred to collectively as FrenchMEN. A man from Germany (we see here with the "y" that "man" is included as a coincidence- you can't take it as "many from Ger" either...) would be called a Germanman and many would be Germanmen. I think they might have said it back in WWII, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If that were the case, I would have expected those terms to have turned up in print at some point. [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Germanman%2CGermanmen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: It could also be _Germanyman_ by analogy with _Chinaman,_ but I doubt that either term saw actual usage.

Comment: No one says "Germanman."