# Why are plurals ‘*humen’ and ‘*Germen’ not conventional?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, gender-neutral

Studying English in school as a second language, I learned that *human being* would be the proper noun to describe a member of the *Homo sapiens* species, but it seems *human* is perfectly acceptable in English nowadays. It can even sometimes substitute (supposedly gender-specific) *man* where that was used in a gender-neutral way, e.g. in *humankind*, but not in **chairhuman, *firehuman* etc.

The gender nouns *man* and (derived) *woman*, however, have their plurals as *men* and *women*, respectively, so why is umlauted **humen* not acceptable at least as an alternative to the regular plural morphem *+s* which is used to form *humans*? The same question applies to some peoples or tribes, e.g. the *Germans* and *Normans*, not **Germen* and **Normen*.

The question even applies if *human* and *man* have different actual etymologies (Romance vs. Germanic), because perceived or folk etymology is often at least as important.

Also, does this effectively render these words [gender-neutral](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251117/politically-correct-substitutes-for-female-and-woman), although they seem to contain the gender-specific morpheme *man* (in singular)?

Comment: You mentioned 'umlaut'. Where does that fit into your question? We don't use umlauts in English. We sometimes use dieresis as in Noël but that is different and doesn't apply to  making plurals.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK There is _s_ plural and umlaut plural in English, e.g. _feet, geese_ and, well, _men_.

Comment: … and null plural of course, e.g. _sheep_.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that although it seems something of a misnomer. Does it differ from I-mutation?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Actually it is not a misnomer, because it only(?) happens with  Germanic roots that also have an umlaut in German etc.: _Fuß > Füße, Gans > Gänse, Mann > Männer_. It’s just much more prolific there.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK [Both *umlaut* and *i-mutation* mean the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-mutation), and it does occur in English. But see also [*ablaut* or *stem-mutation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony) for a broader term related to this phenomenon.

Comment: @chasly: [Umlaut and Ablaut](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/77866/15299) are technical terms referring to types of vowel change in Indo-European historical linguistics. The marks on the German vowels are just indications of it in the German writing system, which is well-adapted to the sounds of the language it transcribes. As you know, English orthography isn't.

Comment: Related question recently asked: [What is the difference between man and human](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279932/what-is-the-difference-between-man-and-human)

Comment: related very closely, almost a perfect duplicate: [**If the plural of ‘man’ is ‘men,’ shouldn’t the plural of ‘German’ be ‘Germen’?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111772/if-the-plural-of-man-is-men-shouldn-t-the-plural-of-german-be-germen)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed, I did not see that question before. Maybe I should edit mine to stronger focus on _human_, despite there being answers already, but then it is close to the one @ ermanen linked to.

Comment: No, you're safe. The answers here are a trillion times better.

Comment: When I read the title, I somehow assumed that they should have been the plurals of *humus* and *germ*...